# How to show results of model on another view MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

I'm new in using MVC framework (like Yii2) and not advanced in PHP, but I know what I'm doing.

I need help with rendering a partial view on another view. I have an `activeForm` and its model is requesting student information from a database. I want to render said student view on another view (staff) and show the results of student on that same view. These views and models work fine when run separately, however, when I submit the `rendePartial` form it does not show the results at all. The page just refresh and go back to its normal state as if I didn't enter any input.

How can I solve this problem? Can anyone help and point me in a right direction? I just need to show the results on the other view, that's it!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you supply a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: update you question add you  related controller/action and view code .

Comment: Thanks!

Here's a link to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/H8YytdBJ and I can also put some of the code here if that wont be too much to read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('index', ['model'=>$model])
```

Try this:

```
$this->render('index', ['model'=>$model])
```

Comment: gmc,

Both of the above does render the same way but the problem I have is that, since the index is rendering on top of another view which has its own form (and a model), I can't see the results of the index view from its model. Maybe I'm missing connection from the controller. I have two views and two models but I want to render index on top of staff-index and show results. I do have show and hide for their DIVs. When I click on student then index render and hide the other and vice versa.

Comment: It is a little bit hard to understand your situation. If I am not wrong, yo have to display different model classes, right? On top, you want to display the 'staff' model and below the form with the form of the student model, right? If that is the case, you should pass the view the two models, and then render one with the staff view and use the other in the form

Comment: Yes, Kind off. Here's my scenario. I have two models classes and two view and they all have forms, right. I want to show the form of each one by selecting a dropdown and also show the results of the staff model on the same view. The problem I have is that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to use two models: one for results and one for searching. You should pass them both to the view. In the controller, you receive the form and load it in the results model. Then you create a new empty model for the search form.

Comment: gmc,

How does that work? So far I created staff model that has findFirstnames query function and also defined the rules of the form on that same model. The same applies to student model too. But since I  want to renderPartial, I can't find an way to see the results of the partial view. I'm doing this because I want to see both views on the same url like http://example.com/lookup. Now I have two links for staff(/staff) and student (/students). 

Do you happen to have an example code of what you mentioned above?

Comment: I have this

[code]<?= Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('index', ['model' => $model] ) ?> [/code]
as a partial render within staff-index view. The form shows up but when I submit it doesn't show results and that's where I get stuck. How can I get that to work. Also, the form on the partial view inherits the form of the staff-index. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The view you posted on pastebin, is 'staff-index'?

Comment: Yes! The view that I want to render( partial) is index.